# No longer ago than yesterday

Tags: expressions, time

I want to say that something happened yesterday and put emphasis on the fact it was only yesterday, that is recently. Can I put it like this:

> I saw him no longer ago than yesterday.

And if I am mistaken, how would you say it, then?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are not wrong and your statement would certainly be understood. But I would simply say "I only saw him yesterday" or "I saw him only yesterday".

Comment: Also - "I *just* saw him yesterday".

Comment: Another - "I saw him _just_ yesterday". See the [Google nGram results for each](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+just+saw+him+yesterday%2CI+saw+him+just+yesterday&year_start=1940&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20just%20saw%20him%20yesterday%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20saw%20him%20just%20yesterday%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: It's actually interesting to look at all four options: [more Google nGram results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+just+saw+him+yesterday%2CI+saw+him+just+yesterday%2CI+only+saw+him+yesterday%2C+I+saw+him+only+yesterday&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20just%20saw%20him%20yesterday%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20saw%20him%20just%20yesterday%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20only%20saw%20him%20yesterday%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20saw%20him%20only%20yesterday%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 6):

Here is another way to say it. This emphasizes the fact that you saw him recently.

> I just saw him yesterday.

Comment: This is probably the most common formulation in fluent speech that people will actually use - both in BrE and AmE.  `Did you hear Dave got hit by a bus??`  ...`That's terrible - I just saw him yesterday!`, etc...  Some of the other suggestions are a bit stuffy and formal for casual speech.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Gill’s answer.

Assuming you did not see him before yesterday and saw him yesterday.

- I first saw him yesterday.
- It was only yesterday that I saw him for the first time.
- I saw him for the first time yesterday.

Assuming you saw him yesterday and also saw him before then.

- I saw him yesterday.
- The last time I saw him was yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

To add to [Ian's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/62314/2127), the type of construction used in

> It was only yesterday that I last saw him.

is called **[a cleft sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleft_sentence)**. Cleft constructions are used to stress one or other part of a sentence.

The cleft construction seems like a nice way to express the Russian "не далее чем вчера", "не далее как вчера" ("no longer ago than yesterday").

Answer (score 0):

I notice when there is a strong emphasis on matters related to a precious day, it is typically referenced by using the term `"...just...".` An example:

> We were driving together **just** yesterday.

Another example:

> It **just** happened last Wednesday.

Answer (score 0):

> long ago

is usually used with a duration:

> - How long ago was that?
> - 3 days ago

I would use "no later than" instead:

> I saw him no **later** than yesterday.

Comment: -1 "No later than" refers to a specified time in future. For example, [see here](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/no-not-later-than). Besides, seeing something at a particular time, as a fact has nothing to do with time duration and neither does the question "How long ago was that?"

Comment: @Rompey "no later than" is also used for past. See this [example](https://books.google.ca/books?id=7ZxOAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA360&lpg=PA360&dq=no+later+than+yesterday&source=bl&ots=hG8r6LpiEh&sig=bKTmVGu_nP4GnBZPZFn0Ht48MCU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1iNz4vJvPAhVs0YMKHWWsDegQ6AEITjAJ#v=onepage&q=no%20later%20than%20yesterday&f=false). The sense here is "as recently as yesterday"

Comment: "How long ago was that" is just an illustration of how one would use "long ago", to show that it is not the correct form for the OP's case.